# Error installing Python 3.5 package 'socket' pycharm

Tags: sockets, package, pycharm, python-3.5

Can't install this package only with the PyCharm or command prompt:

```
Collecting socket
  Using cached socket-0.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ADMIN_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v6d_dkqz\socket\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("Package 'socket' must not be downloaded from pypi")
    RuntimeError: Package 'socket' must not be downloaded from pypi


Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ADMIN_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v6d_dkqz\socket\
```

---

Downloading package separately and installing doesn't work too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you open the file you downloaded, I mean `setup.py`, you notice it consists of a single line:

```
raise RuntimeError("Package 'socket' must not be downloaded from pypi")
```

`socket` module is already included in the standard library. You don't have to download anything. Just type `import socket` and you're all set.