# socket installation error in python2.7

Tags: python

```
 python2.7 -m pip install socket
 Collecting socket
 Using cached socket-0.5.tar.gz
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip-build-NGBb1T/socket/setup.py", line 2, in <module> raise RuntimeError("Package 'socket' must not be downloaded from pypi")
RuntimeError: Package 'socket' must not be downloaded from pypi
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-NGBb1T/socket/

Comment: Is this formatting intended?

Comment: Have you tried just importing it? You don't have to download it. It is included already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068249/error-installing-python-3-5-package-socket-pycharm

Comment: You shouldn't try to `pip install socket`. It's like trying to install `os` with `pip` - no you can't, because the module doesn't exist on PyPI.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use the python socket then you don't need to install it seperately, coz it's already included in standard library.

But if you are trying to install some other package which requires socket lib , then  in `setup.py` of that package, you can see it consists of a single line:

```
raise RuntimeError("Package 'socket' must not be downloaded from pypi")
```

`socket` module is already included in the standard library. You don't have to download anything. Just type `import socket` and you're all set.